# Elasticsearch удаление данных из index

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, index, delete

Elasticsearh v7.4.2 запущен в docker
Не могу понять, как удалить данные из индекса к примеру старше 30 дней.
Удалить необходимо только данные а не сам индекс.

Все что я нашел в документации (видимо плохо искал) касается удаления индексов а не данных (документов) в нем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть **Delete by query API**. Метод поддерживает любые запросы которые можно использовать при поиске (Search API).

```
POST имя_индекса/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "range" : {
        "timestamp" : {
            "lte" : "now-30d/d"
        }
   }
}
```

Ссылка на документацию:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html